# Angular 17 SSR - Share Data from Server to Angular Component

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-ssr

I'm developing payment app using angular 17 ssr. 
In requirement, need to capture

- **Server IP**
- **Server MAC Address**
- **User agent**

using **Address** package, I tried to capture the required information .

FileName: Server.ts

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import express from 'express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname, join, resolve } from 'node:path';
import bootstrap from './src/main.server';
import { ip, mac } from 'address';
import { IpAddressToken, MacAddressToken } from './src/utils/injectTokens';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(ipaddress: string, macAddress: string): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const serverDistFolder = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
  const browserDistFolder = resolve(serverDistFolder, '../browser');
  const indexHtml = join(serverDistFolder, 'index.server.html');

  const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', browserDistFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(browserDistFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [
          { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl },
          { provide: IpAddressToken, useValue: ipaddress,multi:true },
          { provide: MacAddressToken, useValue: macAddress,multi:true },
        ],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {

  let ipAddress: string = ip()!;
  let macAddress!: string;
  mac((err, add) => {
    macAddress = add!;
  });
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;
  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app(ipAddress, macAddress);
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
    console.log(`Server IP: ${ipAddress} - MAC: ${macAddress}`);
  });

}

run();
```

InjectionToken.ts

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";

export const IpAddressToken = new InjectionToken<string>("IP Address");
export const MacAddressToken = new InjectionToken<string>("MAC Address");
```

[image]

I developed code upto this stage,
Now, I'm not sure how to share this information to Angular Components.
Do I'm going in right way ??

Comment: You can use the [`TransferState`](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2024-version-a617a83324a1#9458)

Comment: Could you suggest me without .NET, its sperate SSR project.

Comment: Actually all you have to do is use the new [`provideClientHydration()`](https://angular.io/guide/hydration) feature from angular 17. Your app sends webrequests during SSR, then puts the responses in the TransferState, and retrieves them again in the browser

Comment: @Pieterjan Thanks for the help. I have taken TransferState with provider factory pattern.